# flutter project failed to make gradle sync and build bundle. Error: Type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation

Tags: flutter, groovy

When i make flutter run command app is successfully executing in the mobile device or emulator, but when i try to build an apk through open for editing in android studio mode. i am unable to load the packages and unable to build the app bundle.

I got the error in the terminal view as:

**1. Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
2. Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 6.7.

```
  Possible solution:
   - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 7.2 version and re-import the project
```

**
Then i have upgraded the gradle version **6.7-all.zip** to **7.2-bin.zip** then i got the error of

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' (type 'FlutterTask').

  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assets' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'assetsDirectory' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'buildMode' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'fastStart' doesn't have a configured value.

    Reason: This property isn't marked as optional and no value has been configured.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Assign a value to 'fastStart'.
    2. Mark property 'fastStart' as optional.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#value_not_set for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'FlutterPlugin' type 'FlutterTask' property 'flutterExecutable' is missing an input or output annotation.

    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add an input or output annotation.
    2. Mark it as @Internal.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        35.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here is the details of configurations that iam using:
1. flutter version : 2.0.6
2. dart version:    2.12.3
3. android/build.gradle version: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
4. android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
5. Java versions: 11.0.20
6. android/build.gradle Kotlin version: ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

can any one suggest me what should i have to do to generate apk bundle and app bundle. what changes do i need to do, thanks in advance :).

Iam trying to generate apk bundle or app bundle for both testing and app release in playstore but iam unable to generate the apk or app bundle. actually i have upgraded the flutter code from 1.22.6 to 2.0.6 which is flutter null safety, where so far i have updated the syntax to null safety but the issue raise when i try to give an apk for the testing to generate apk bundle.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/79167 2 years ago.  What version of the flutter plugin are you using?

Comment: thanks for the reply, iam using the flutter version 2.0.6

Comment: I think that's from 30/04/2021. If your want to update gradle, you'll need to update flutter

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i'll do that.

Comment: You can improve readability of your question using some formatting, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Hey, the issue is resolved, by upgrading the flutter version to 3.7.0 and later i have faced a challenges in android/app/build.gradle file, then i have creted a sample project and copied the sample project android/app/build.gradle components and replaced with the attributes which are required for me, and later i have upgraded the kotlin version based on android version which you have installed: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details and upgraded gradle version 7.2.1. issue resolved for me.

Comment: @AgainPsychoX, thanks for the suggestion and link, next time i will improve it.

Comment: @tim_yates, thanks for you suggestion, the issue got resolved.